# Program started from batch file starts in background

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that I run from a flash drive. This file attempts to

```
1. Close 2 programs
2. Update data on the computer based on the data on the flash drive
3. Restart the programs
```

The code in this batch is:

```
taskkill /IM "MyProgram".exe
taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq MyProgram.exe"

copy e:\File1.xml C:\Folder\SubFolder1\Themes\Data\File1.xml /Y
copy e:\File2.xml C:\Folder\SubFolder1\Themes\Data\File2.xml /Y
copy e:\File3.xml C:\Folder\SubFolder2\Themes\Data\File3.xml /Y
copy e:\File4.xml C:\Folder\SubFolder2\Themes\Data\File4.xml /Y

start /MAX "" "C:\Folder\SubFolder2\MyProgram.exe"
start /MAX "" "C:\Folder\SubFolder1\MyProgram.exe"
```

The first two steps work fine, with the commands that are on lines 1-6. My issue starts with step 3 and the commands on lines 7 and 8.

Is there something wrong with the batch commands?

EDIT: After digging a little more, I have found that the programs appear to be starting in the background. When looking at task manager, the programs appear in the "Background Processes" section instead of showing in the foreground as expected.

Comment: Depending on the current computers drives the letter `e:` maybe wrong. Either use only `\` or take the drive from the running batch with `%~d0`

Comment: @LotPings - The first 2 steps are working correctly. The e: drive stays the same between the computers that are used in the process.

Comment: There is no guarantie to get always the same drive letter. The first two commands don't use any drive letter. A test with `for /l %%x in (1,1,4) do copy "%~d0\file%%x.xml" "C:\Folder\SubFolder2\Themes\Data\File%%x.xml" /Y` instead of the repetitions won't harm.

Comment: I would try starting the programs like this: `start "" /MAX /D "C:\Folder\SubFolder2\" MyProgram.exe`. I doubt this will make a difference though.

Comment: I have added some more information based on discovery that the processes are starting in the background based on the Task Manager

Comment: @rdbradshaw, I thought that was a given based on your question title.

Comment: @Squashman - DOH! forgot that I put that there. It did not appear that comments were relating to that piece so was trying to point focus. Thanks

Comment: @rdbradshaw, did you try my suggestion.  I had something similar happen with a program that one of our programmers wrote in house.  When the program starts it is probably thinking the working directory is the folder from where the batch file was launched.  The /D option will tell the program to start in the same folder the executable is located in.  Your program may not be able to find its configuration files.

Comment: @Squashman - Bingo! that worked. Add as answer and I will accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe is happening is your program does not know where the configuration files are located because the working directory is where the batch file started itself.  So your program is looking for its files on your usb drive.  By using the /D option with the START command it will switch the working directory to whatever path you set it to.

```
start "" /MAX /D "C:\Folder\SubFolder2\" MyProgram.exe
```